# How to make multiple calls to the same function fire in order, when function includes asynchronous actions

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, race-condition

I'm dealing with a race condition, and trying to sort out how to solve it.

I've got multiple pieces of code that call the same function. This function calls `fetch` on an API endpoint and makes DOM modifications according to the result. The function may be called on page load, or in response to user action. The user may trigger the function call multiple times.

Things get broken if the DOM modification for a later call happens before a modification from an earlier call, which occasionally happens.

Is there a common pattern for ensuring that these DOM modifications occur in order, even if the fetch calls do not?

I'm thinking creating some sort of a queue, where I add a timestamped row to an array when the method is called, and then attach the `fetch` results to that row when fetch completes, then make all the DOM modifications down the list of timestamps until I hit a row without a result. Does that make sense or is there an off the shelf solution or common pattern I'm missing here?

```
function getContent() {
    fetch(url)
        .then((response)) => modifyDOM(); // Make this part run in sequence.
}

// for reasons not shown here, the first call takes so long that the second one
// completes its DOM modification first. This race condition breaks my content.
getContent();
getContent();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep track of a persistent Promise that gets reassigned to the new request when the function is called:

```
let prom = Promise.resolve();
function getContent() {
    const promToReturn = prom
      .then(() => fetch(url))
      .then(modifyDOM);
    // continue the chain even if there's an error during one of them
    prom = promToReturn.catch(() => undefined);
    // while returning the original Promise whose results and errors can be seen outside
    return promToReturn;
}
```

This way, only one request will be going on at any one time, at most. Sequential calls to `getContent` only result in one ongoing request at a time. `getContent(); getContent();` will result in one request, which finishes and modifies the DOM, and then after that's done, another request that then modifies the DOM.

Comment: Can you explain this a little more? Does this require that I throw an error if I’m running modifyDOM() too soon? Currently no errors are happening, just content in a broken state. All my DOM modifications run, but I need them to run in the correct order.

Comment: It'll just mean that sequential calls to `getContent` only result in one ongoing request at a time, which sounds like what you were trying to get. The only errors that might occur would be those resulting from the `fetch` call or from the `modifyDOM` call. Eg `getContent(); getContent()` will result in one request, which finishes and modifies the DOM, and then after that's done, another request that then modifies the DOM.

Comment: Does this mean additional requests will start when previous ones finish, or do additional requests just not execute?

Comment: When the previous one finishes, see this part of the comment: *and then after that's done, another request that then modifies the DOM*

Comment: I appreciate all the help. Do I need to do anything with that returned promise when I call `getContent()` then?

Comment: The code would probably make the most sense if it did - it's pretty strange to have a standalone asynchronous function that has side-effects on its own, especially when the order of those side effects seem to matter to the outside.

Comment: Yes, I'm troubleshooting clunky code. It's a site that is mostly templated on the backend with a bit of AJAX functionality in some views. There's no state management, there's ugly side effects, but at the moment I'm trying to just avoid the race condition rather than refactor entirely.